# d3 v5 circle swarm plot dynamically adjust force to account for variable radius size

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a swarm plot that shows ranges from `0` to `1` on a linear x axis and size via the SVG circle's radius attribute. Snippet below:

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

I have had modest success by setting the `strength` to a low value and `forceCollide` to a high value:

```
  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
  .force("x", d3.forceX(function(d) {
  return xScale(d.pequity);
}).strength(0.01))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(function(d) {
  return 100;
}).strength(0.01))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(10).iterations(1))
  .stop();
```

However there are many instances where the circles are all lumped together.

My intended goal is to have each circle stand apart (not overlapping), but at the same time I want the circles to be placed closed together. I imagine this would entail variable force settings, not sure how small circles next to big circles should be handled (and vice versa).

### Question

How can I adjust my force logic to account for variable radius sizes in my swarm circles such that each circle is close but not engulfed by another circle?

Comment: The radius provided to d3.forceCollide can be provided as a function: `d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) { return d.radius; })` - is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @AndrewReid I tried that but all it did was lock the circles down (strong force?). I just noticed there may be something wrong with my snippet, I will try to fix that awhile