# D3.js v5 circle swarm plot adjust force to account for variable-sized radii

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a swarm plot that shows ranges from `0` to `1` on a linear x axis and size via the SVG circle's radius attribute. Snippet below:

```js
var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:100, right:100};

var height = 200;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

//var tsvData = d3.tsv('fmc-equity.tsv');

//tsvData.then(function(rawData) {

  //var data = rawData.map(function(d) {
//return {fmc:d.fmc, pequity:+d.pequity, total:+d.total, rank:+d.rank}
  //});

  var data = [{'pequity': 1.0, 'total': 24902636438.0},
 {'pequity': 1.0, 'total': 8204868902.0},
 {'pequity': 1.0, 'total': 6658546024.0},
 {'pequity': 1.0, 'total': 6126023357.0},
 {'pequity': 1.0, 'total': 2193415702.0},
 {'pequity': 1.0, 'total': 1734784625.0},
 {'pequity': 1.0, 'total': 1296048848.0},
 {'pequity': 1.0, 'total': 308649243.8},
 {'pequity': 1.0, 'total': 295207349.3},
 {'pequity': 1.0, 'total': 234857862.9},
 {'pequity': 1.0, 'total': 156598861.9},
 {'pequity': 1.0, 'total': 104983353.0},
 {'pequity': 1.0, 'total': 63690617.76},
 {'pequity': 1.0, 'total': 59401648.51},
 {'pequity': 0.975623135, 'total': 14007871265.0},
 {'pequity': 0.967237964, 'total': 1685804854.0},
 {'pequity': 0.963917349, 'total': 293309822.9},
 {'pequity': 0.934185443, 'total': 2917969779.0},
 {'pequity': 0.933316698, 'total': 30102340057.0},
 {'pequity': 0.915294851, 'total': 24722091961.0},
 {'pequity': 0.913848269, 'total': 25585870482.0},
 {'pequity': 0.913408996, 'total': 2991804061.0},
 {'pequity': 0.892768552, 'total': 9977890414.0},
 {'pequity': 0.845989331, 'total': 88124798828.0},
 {'pequity': 0.829158756, 'total': 1180176138.0},
 {'pequity': 0.827893585, 'total': 21493562671.0},
 {'pequity': 0.815844492, 'total': 1141920435.0},
 {'pequity': 0.793349904, 'total': 45529532260.0},
 {'pequity': 0.784721035, 'total': 163020000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.778621751, 'total': 2758477982.0},
 {'pequity': 0.776066588, 'total': 96073251741.0},
 {'pequity': 0.752238939, 'total': 34388436875.0},
 {'pequity': 0.742142911, 'total': 1406030271.0},
 {'pequity': 0.740334287, 'total': 4711578569.0},
 {'pequity': 0.738044554, 'total': 72969280487.0},
 {'pequity': 0.728912674, 'total': 51810952821.0},
 {'pequity': 0.723159895, 'total': 147101000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.717957188, 'total': 380923000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.702860894, 'total': 1971690322.0},
 {'pequity': 0.700934687, 'total': 334084000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.684489847, 'total': 162390000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.679992279, 'total': 57956445277.0},
 {'pequity': 0.669998233, 'total': 3758791332.0},
 {'pequity': 0.667230968, 'total': 187355000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.653736462, 'total': 186999000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.650328323, 'total': 76326103402.0},
 {'pequity': 0.642256236, 'total': 244641000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.642232384, 'total': 21058144224.0},
 {'pequity': 0.634697091, 'total': 36845417753.0},
 {'pequity': 0.625246046, 'total': 7505300217.0},
 {'pequity': 0.622668225, 'total': 287937000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.615894348, 'total': 390042000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.614523365, 'total': 493581000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.610259063, 'total': 187658000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.606075625, 'total': 20568282534.0},
 {'pequity': 0.566893948, 'total': 13561590623.0},
 {'pequity': 0.562164622, 'total': 1752893048.0},
 {'pequity': 0.548193052, 'total': 54080529801.0},
 {'pequity': 0.547672307, 'total': 333058000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.503813337, 'total': 61882066527.0},
 {'pequity': 0.499762105, 'total': 549015425.1},
 {'pequity': 0.492513345, 'total': 1922398097.0},
 {'pequity': 0.482375439, 'total': 174165000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.481469613, 'total': 23194895826.0},
 {'pequity': 0.473987425, 'total': 44789781494.0},
 {'pequity': 0.470739815, 'total': 222499000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.469682435, 'total': 72718319931.0},
 {'pequity': 0.460955268, 'total': 52888450676.0},
 {'pequity': 0.454973874, 'total': 90023055250.0},
 {'pequity': 0.44679832, 'total': 4754240139.0},
 {'pequity': 0.445399024, 'total': 1860137274.0},
 {'pequity': 0.445084958, 'total': 50012066209.0},
 {'pequity': 0.434558735, 'total': 49289017295.0},
 {'pequity': 0.428538866, 'total': 41569179291.0},
 {'pequity': 0.41951359, 'total': 7018167989.0},
 {'pequity': 0.396038585, 'total': 18903076296.0},
 {'pequity': 0.385996777, 'total': 94845890023.0},
 {'pequity': 0.3812259, 'total': 98841184094.0},
 {'pequity': 0.371094794, 'total': 1431333898.0},
 {'pequity': 0.365174764, 'total': 257971000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.35268716, 'total': 20795433552.0},
 {'pequity': 0.351769714, 'total': 46931277851.0},
 {'pequity': 0.345540928, 'total': 100671761.5},
 {'pequity': 0.345042619, 'total': 255962000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.314932486, 'total': 5787699612.0},
 {'pequity': 0.309844838, 'total': 3188814099.0},
 {'pequity': 0.302505711, 'total': 369297000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.300290501, 'total': 61328595371.0},
 {'pequity': 0.295468038, 'total': 20050870773.0},
 {'pequity': 0.288731133, 'total': 28168716566.0},
 {'pequity': 0.28162825, 'total': 64373673559.0},
 {'pequity': 0.276328709, 'total': 16485758359.0},
 {'pequity': 0.272881943, 'total': 16147599057.0},
 {'pequity': 0.271453039, 'total': 2928943682.0},
 {'pequity': 0.266499192, 'total': 21680176766.0},
 {'pequity': 0.263242046, 'total': 26901134796.0},
 {'pequity': 0.256506237, 'total': 27264058954.0},
 {'pequity': 0.24385484, 'total': 11826556257.0},
 {'pequity': 0.212618709, 'total': 142548000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.206427, 'total': 987906653.4},
 {'pequity': 0.180456114, 'total': 23091916753.0},
 {'pequity': 0.1795785, 'total': 11992158423.0},
 {'pequity': 0.179430445, 'total': 3487165569.0},
 {'pequity': 0.178686517, 'total': 6136684295.0},
 {'pequity': 0.165903599, 'total': 3174960123.0},
 {'pequity': 0.157774552, 'total': 1102371297.0},
 {'pequity': 0.154730021, 'total': 152300000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.153370048, 'total': 277961000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.150154936, 'total': 9120805049.0},
 {'pequity': 0.138031161, 'total': 13585651275.0},
 {'pequity': 0.132149555, 'total': 5866131520.0},
 {'pequity': 0.127044391, 'total': 107968000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.118377486, 'total': 192425000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.112239901, 'total': 21685959074.0},
 {'pequity': 0.10993787, 'total': 138104000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.102825314, 'total': 664998672.3},
 {'pequity': 0.100750551, 'total': 5070893025.0},
 {'pequity': 0.098320627, 'total': 11934005108.0},
 {'pequity': 0.085851591, 'total': 95949611145.0},
 {'pequity': 0.084841651, 'total': 130194000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.075753702, 'total': 4242368665.0},
 {'pequity': 0.070840029, 'total': 65237058794.0},
 {'pequity': 0.069366366, 'total': 8924237004.0},
 {'pequity': 0.065697627, 'total': 125058000000.0},
 {'pequity': 0.062568593, 'total': 30980215635.0},
 {'pequity': 0.045230625, 'total': 15276099395.0},
 {'pequity': 0.044570177, 'total': 3394981597.0},
 {'pequity': 0.033796831, 'total': 458403426.1},
 {'pequity': 0.032226083, 'total': 1479573059.0},
 {'pequity': 0.026393495, 'total': 2219070269.0},
 {'pequity': 0.025384872, 'total': 27453319886.0},
 {'pequity': 0.023300471, 'total': 38244344058.0},
 {'pequity': 0.023052145, 'total': 32731585574.0},
 {'pequity': 0.022364885, 'total': 85876344739.0},
 {'pequity': 0.01707023, 'total': 99129084307.0},
 {'pequity': 0.016398224, 'total': 32021523348.0},
 {'pequity': 0.012356364, 'total': 29362367552.0},
 {'pequity': 0.005433651, 'total': 7857569806.0},
 {'pequity': 0.00248832, 'total': 11804897194.0},
 {'pequity': 0.001381446, 'total': 2959158279.0},
 {'pequity': 0.0, 'total': 1260997046.0}];

  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0,width])
  .domain([0,1]);

  var rScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([5,50])
  .domain([0,500000000000]);

  data.forEach(function (d,i) {
  d.x = xScale(d.pequity);
  d.y = 100;
  });

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
  .force("x", d3.forceX(function(d) {
  return xScale(d.pequity);
}).strength(0.01))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(function(d) {
  return 100;
}).strength(0.01))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(10).iterations(1))
  .stop();

  for (var i = 0; i < 75; ++i) {
  simulation.tick();
  }

  var circles = graphGroup.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {return rScale(d.total)})
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x;})
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y;})
  .style('fill', function(d) {return "#003366"; });

//})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

I have had modest success by setting the `strength` to a low value and `forceCollide` to a high value:

```
  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
  .force("x", d3.forceX(function(d) {
  return xScale(d.pequity);
}).strength(0.01))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(function(d) {
  return 100;
}).strength(0.01))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(10).iterations(1))
  .stop();
```

However there are many instances where the circles are all lumped together.

My intended goal is to have each circle stand apart (not overlapping), but at the same time I want the circles to be placed closed together. I imagine this would entail variable force settings, not sure how small circles next to big circles should be handled (and vice versa).

Also, when I tried:

```
.force('collide', function(d) {return d3.forceCollide(rScale(d.total)).iterations(1)})
```

It reverted to an iteration that resembled a high force setting (all circles snapped to the center line). It seems that `.force('collide',` does not support dynamic attribute. Though, I could be mistaken.

### Question

How can I adjust my force logic to account for variable radius sizes in my swarm circles such that each circle is close but not engulfed by another circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [previously suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63627257/d3-v5-circle-swarm-plot-dynamically-adjust-force-to-account-for-variable-radius#comment112513316_63627257) you just need to pass the radius of each circle to `d3.forceCollide`. In your case:

```
.force("collide", d3.forceCollide(d => rScale(d.total)))
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var margins = {
  top: 20,
  bottom: 300,
  left: 100,
  right: 100
};

var height = 200;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width + margins.left + margins.right;
var totalHeight = height + margins.top + margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', totalWidth)
  .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")");

//var tsvData = d3.tsv('fmc-equity.tsv');

//tsvData.then(function(rawData) {

//var data = rawData.map(function(d) {
//return {fmc:d.fmc, pequity:+d.pequity, total:+d.total, rank:+d.rank}
//});

var data = [{
    'pequity': 1.0,
    'total': 24902636438.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 1.0,
    'total': 8204868902.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 1.0,
    'total': 6658546024.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 1.0,
    'total': 6126023357.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 1.0,
    'total': 2193415702.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 1.0,
    'total': 1734784625.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 1.0,
    'total': 1296048848.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 1.0,
    'total': 308649243.8
  },
  {
    'pequity': 1.0,
    'total': 295207349.3
  },
  {
    'pequity': 1.0,
    'total': 234857862.9
  },
  {
    'pequity': 1.0,
    'total': 156598861.9
  },
  {
    'pequity': 1.0,
    'total': 104983353.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 1.0,
    'total': 63690617.76
  },
  {
    'pequity': 1.0,
    'total': 59401648.51
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.975623135,
    'total': 14007871265.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.967237964,
    'total': 1685804854.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.963917349,
    'total': 293309822.9
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.934185443,
    'total': 2917969779.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.933316698,
    'total': 30102340057.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.915294851,
    'total': 24722091961.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.913848269,
    'total': 25585870482.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.913408996,
    'total': 2991804061.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.892768552,
    'total': 9977890414.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.845989331,
    'total': 88124798828.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.829158756,
    'total': 1180176138.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.827893585,
    'total': 21493562671.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.815844492,
    'total': 1141920435.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.793349904,
    'total': 45529532260.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.784721035,
    'total': 163020000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.778621751,
    'total': 2758477982.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.776066588,
    'total': 96073251741.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.752238939,
    'total': 34388436875.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.742142911,
    'total': 1406030271.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.740334287,
    'total': 4711578569.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.738044554,
    'total': 72969280487.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.728912674,
    'total': 51810952821.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.723159895,
    'total': 147101000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.717957188,
    'total': 380923000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.702860894,
    'total': 1971690322.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.700934687,
    'total': 334084000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.684489847,
    'total': 162390000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.679992279,
    'total': 57956445277.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.669998233,
    'total': 3758791332.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.667230968,
    'total': 187355000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.653736462,
    'total': 186999000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.650328323,
    'total': 76326103402.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.642256236,
    'total': 244641000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.642232384,
    'total': 21058144224.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.634697091,
    'total': 36845417753.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.625246046,
    'total': 7505300217.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.622668225,
    'total': 287937000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.615894348,
    'total': 390042000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.614523365,
    'total': 493581000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.610259063,
    'total': 187658000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.606075625,
    'total': 20568282534.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.566893948,
    'total': 13561590623.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.562164622,
    'total': 1752893048.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.548193052,
    'total': 54080529801.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.547672307,
    'total': 333058000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.503813337,
    'total': 61882066527.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.499762105,
    'total': 549015425.1
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.492513345,
    'total': 1922398097.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.482375439,
    'total': 174165000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.481469613,
    'total': 23194895826.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.473987425,
    'total': 44789781494.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.470739815,
    'total': 222499000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.469682435,
    'total': 72718319931.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.460955268,
    'total': 52888450676.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.454973874,
    'total': 90023055250.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.44679832,
    'total': 4754240139.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.445399024,
    'total': 1860137274.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.445084958,
    'total': 50012066209.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.434558735,
    'total': 49289017295.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.428538866,
    'total': 41569179291.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.41951359,
    'total': 7018167989.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.396038585,
    'total': 18903076296.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.385996777,
    'total': 94845890023.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.3812259,
    'total': 98841184094.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.371094794,
    'total': 1431333898.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.365174764,
    'total': 257971000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.35268716,
    'total': 20795433552.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.351769714,
    'total': 46931277851.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.345540928,
    'total': 100671761.5
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.345042619,
    'total': 255962000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.314932486,
    'total': 5787699612.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.309844838,
    'total': 3188814099.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.302505711,
    'total': 369297000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.300290501,
    'total': 61328595371.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.295468038,
    'total': 20050870773.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.288731133,
    'total': 28168716566.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.28162825,
    'total': 64373673559.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.276328709,
    'total': 16485758359.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.272881943,
    'total': 16147599057.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.271453039,
    'total': 2928943682.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.266499192,
    'total': 21680176766.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.263242046,
    'total': 26901134796.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.256506237,
    'total': 27264058954.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.24385484,
    'total': 11826556257.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.212618709,
    'total': 142548000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.206427,
    'total': 987906653.4
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.180456114,
    'total': 23091916753.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.1795785,
    'total': 11992158423.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.179430445,
    'total': 3487165569.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.178686517,
    'total': 6136684295.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.165903599,
    'total': 3174960123.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.157774552,
    'total': 1102371297.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.154730021,
    'total': 152300000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.153370048,
    'total': 277961000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.150154936,
    'total': 9120805049.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.138031161,
    'total': 13585651275.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.132149555,
    'total': 5866131520.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.127044391,
    'total': 107968000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.118377486,
    'total': 192425000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.112239901,
    'total': 21685959074.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.10993787,
    'total': 138104000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.102825314,
    'total': 664998672.3
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.100750551,
    'total': 5070893025.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.098320627,
    'total': 11934005108.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.085851591,
    'total': 95949611145.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.084841651,
    'total': 130194000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.075753702,
    'total': 4242368665.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.070840029,
    'total': 65237058794.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.069366366,
    'total': 8924237004.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.065697627,
    'total': 125058000000.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.062568593,
    'total': 30980215635.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.045230625,
    'total': 15276099395.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.044570177,
    'total': 3394981597.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.033796831,
    'total': 458403426.1
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.032226083,
    'total': 1479573059.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.026393495,
    'total': 2219070269.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.025384872,
    'total': 27453319886.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.023300471,
    'total': 38244344058.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.023052145,
    'total': 32731585574.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.022364885,
    'total': 85876344739.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.01707023,
    'total': 99129084307.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.016398224,
    'total': 32021523348.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.012356364,
    'total': 29362367552.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.005433651,
    'total': 7857569806.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.00248832,
    'total': 11804897194.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.001381446,
    'total': 2959158279.0
  },
  {
    'pequity': 0.0,
    'total': 1260997046.0
  }
];

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain([0, 1]);

var rScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([5, 50])
  .domain([0, 500000000000]);

data.forEach(function(d, i) {
  d.x = xScale(d.pequity);
  d.y = 100;
});

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
  .force("x", d3.forceX(function(d) {
    return xScale(d.pequity);
  }).strength(0.01))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(function(d) {
    return 100;
  }).strength(0.01))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(d => rScale(d.total)))
  .stop();

simulation.tick(75);

var circles = graphGroup.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return rScale(d.total)
  })
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  });

//})
```

```css
circle {
  fill: tan;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

---

Some observations:

1. In D3 v5, this...

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < 75; ++i) {
       simulation.tick();
   }
   ```

   can be just:

   ```
   simulation.tick(75);
   ```
2. You are encoding a value as the circle **area**, not the circle radius. As such, I strongly suggest that you use a **square root scale** instead of a linear scale.